# Desktop Environment is a custom OS

Tags: c, operating-system, desktop, environment

If I write an OS using c, how would I make the desktop? Could I implement Java, or is there a way to do this is the C programming language? I've never done anything with any sort of graphics in C. Does anybody know the answer, much less a tutorial or a way to get started and learn how to write the desktop environment?

Comment: Classic example of the Dunning-Kruger effect

Answer (score 4):

The Gnome desktop on Linux is written in C (mostly).

But if you write an OS, the desktop is not your priority; getting right important things like processes, scheduling, threads, drivers, protection, authentification, .... is more important, and time consuming.

Don't confuse the [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) with the [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system). Most computers (probably the Web server at `stackoverflow` providing you this very answer, running in some datacenter) don't have any desktop environments. They do have an OS.

About OSes, read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/). You probably are writing some [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)), so look into [osdev.org](https://osdev.org/) for guidance.

About desktop environments, they are specific to the [display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server) provided and used by your OS. On my Linux box in 2019, that server is [Xorg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server) (but maybe you are using [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol))), and the rules related to desktop environments include [ICCCM](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/) & [EWMH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Window_Manager_Hints). And [GNOME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME)  (and also `Xorg`) is running in [user-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring) and [user space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space).

Comment: See also http://tunes.org/ which has (deep inside) many resources...